# Why is the loop-lvm device storage not suitable for production?

Tags: docker, filesystems

I see this assertion everywhere, but have not seen a good explanation yet.

What are the likely consequences of using loop-lvm mode as the Docker storage mode in a productive environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop LVM will give you really bad performance, will result in high usage of resources, which makes it unsuitable for production. Many issues that are reported with devicemapper are related to using devicemapper with loop-lvm, so to use devicemapper for production, make sure to configure it properly. You can find information on how to configure devicemapper for production in the documentation; https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/

Depending on what system and kernel you're running, you could also consider one of the other graph drivers, such as `aufs`, `overlay`, `btrfs` or `zfs`. The documentation has information about how they compare as well, because which storage-driver to use may depend on your use-case; *how* you're using Docker. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Comment: I'm using `devicemapper` with a `thinpool` LVM in RHEL / CentOS, but got it: performance. Is data more likely to get corrupted or something like that?

Comment: If you run out of disk space, the pool corrupts and you won't be able to recover from that. We're adding an option to docker 1.11 just for that https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20786